# Xcode 8 - Framework not found -sqlite3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, sqlite

I integrated animation with Quartzcode, it's work fine but when I launch Xcode, since this modification, xcode crash on signin product step ( before build ). I have some pods installed for this project, and I think one of these pods create a conflict with my animation. So I deleted the "conflict pod", but since I have some errors :

> ld: framework not found -lsqlite3 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

But, when I go to linked framework, it's ok :

[image: Screen]
[image: Screen2]

How can I resolve this problem ? I can't build my project, I already deleted DerivedData folder

I deleted and reinstalled the pod, but always the same result

Comment: Will you share your project ? I will check it and return back you soon

Comment: I'm currently uploading project on a file hosting

Comment: It seems that Url is blocked. Can u send me on my mail ?

Comment: Archive is too big for email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your build settings, just remove the last lines:

```
-framework
-lsqlite3
-ObjC
```

and it will work, make it look like this:

[image]

What causes it, is you having a -framework declaration without a framework afterwards, but a -l sqlite3 and then -ObjC.

Comment: Thanks, I can build again my project !